# Sencha Touch model.save() and updating without additional load

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am wondering why I cannot do the following:

```
newChallenge = Ext.create('App.model.User', {name:'donald'});
newChallenge.save();
*** After another user action ***
newChallenge.set('name','george');
newChallenge.save();
```

The problem I am having is that the second save/update is not even triggering an AJAX patch/post to the server after the first one and not setting the name to 'george'

I don't see any errors in the log or updates in the DB.

**Model:**

```
Ext.define('App.model.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    requires: [
        'Ext.data.identifier.Uuid'
    ],
    config: {
        identifier: 'uuid',
        fields: [
            { name: 'id', type: 'auto', persist: false },
            { name: 'name', type: 'string' }

        ]           
        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            api: {
                create: App.util.Config.getApiUrl('user_profile'),
                update: App.util.Config.getApiUrl('user_profile'),
                read: App.util.Config.getApiUrl('user_profile')
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            },
            writer: { 
                type: 'json-custom-writer-extended',
                writeAllFields: true,
                nameProperty: 'mapping'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Server Response (TastyPie):**

```
{
   "name":"george",
   "id":35,
   "resource_uri":"/app/api/1/user/35/",
   "start_date":"2013-08-06T14:49:11.030298"
}
```

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to state what the problem, don't you? You know, what I expect, what I get instead...

Anyway, your code is broken because it relies on the call to `save()` being synchronous (meaning the first call will block until the response has been received and processed), while it is not. You should begin by fixing that:

```
newChallenge = Ext.create('App.model.User', {name:'donald'});
newChallenge.save({
    success: function(model) {
        newChallenge.set('name','george');
        newChallenge.save(); // you should handle error here too
    }
    // you should handle error cases too...
});
```

Comment: Thanks rixo. I updated the question per your suggestion. The second save is happening after a second submit, so synchronous blocking isn't an issue. Error cases are also in there, just omitted for question clarity.